# Configuration file .htaccess(php) has an extension?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I read [this article](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/how-to-use-htaccess/) that says .htaccess is the filename in full, it is not a file extensión. so what is the extensión of the file?

Comment: 1) That's not the PHP config file.  2) `.htaccess` is the full name of the file, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

The filename is the extension, and the extension is the filename.

`.htaccess` comes from Apache, which started out on Unix systems, where files whose names start with `.` are "hidden" files. That's all - it's supposed to be hidden since it contains directives/settings FOR a site, but is not technically PART of a site, as .html/.jpg/css files would be.

Comment: you're just reading too much into it. technically `.foo` is an extension, but since `.foo` is a VALID filename on unix systems, it doesn't necessary mean it's an extension. e.g. `kittens.jpg` is a file whose extension is .jpg. `.kittens.jpg` is a HIDDEN file with an extension `.jpg`, but since Windows defines anything after a `.` as the extension, from a Windows perspective `.kittens.jpg` IS the extension.